# Good replacement for D&D Insider character builder?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-sheets, dnd-insider

I love the D&D Insider character builder for D&D 4E.  However, since it uses Silverlight and support for Silverlight is quickly being dropped from most modern browsers, I am looking for a possible replacement.  Does anyone know of a good program that I could use to manage my character sheets?  Thanks!